# IFC.js show/hide layers and components

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ifc

I'm wrapping "web-ifc-viewer" in an angular application.
I've some troubles to hide and show components inside the IFC.

I've started from this [example](https://github.com/IFCjs/hello-world/blob/main/examples/web-ifc-three/hiding/app.js) but I need to build a generic BIM viewer, so I can't define any category to prior.

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {IfcViewerAPI} from "web-ifc-viewer";
import {Subject, takeUntil} from "rxjs";
import {AppThemes, BimViewerService} from "./bim-viewer.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'almaviva-bim-viewer',
  templateUrl: './bim-viewer.template.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bim-viewer.component.scss']
})
export class BimViewerComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('viewerContainer')
  container!: ElementRef;
  viewer?: IfcViewerAPI;
  model: any;
  ifcElement: any;
  loadingValue: number = 0;


  constructor() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (this.container) {
      this.viewer = new IfcViewerAPI({container: this.container.nativeElement});
      this.loadIfc('/assets/sample.ifc');
    }

  }

  private async loadIfc(url: string) {
    try {
      if (this.viewer) {
        await this.viewer.IFC.loader.ifcManager.useWebWorkers(true, '/assets/IFCWorker.js');
        await this.viewer.IFC.setWasmPath("wasm/");
        this.viewer.axes.setAxes(1000);
        this.viewer.grid.setGrid(1000);
        await this.viewer.IFC.loader.ifcManager.applyWebIfcConfig({
          USE_FAST_BOOLS: true,
          COORDINATE_TO_ORIGIN: true
        });
        this.viewer.IFC.loader.ifcManager.setOnProgress(
          (event) => {
            this.loadingValue = Math.floor((event.loaded * 100) / event.total);
          }
        )
        this.model = await this.viewer.IFC.loadIfcUrl(url);
        const project = await this.viewer.IFC.getSpatialStructure(this.model.modelID, true);
        this.ifcElement = project.children[0];
        await this.viewer.shadowDropper.renderShadow(this.model.modelID);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  async toggleLayer(event: Event, layer: any) {
      const subset = this.viewer?.IFC.loader.ifcManager.createSubset({
      modelID: this.model.modelID,
      ids: [layer.expressID],
      removePrevious: true,
      customID: `${layer.expressID}-custom-id`
    });
    if (subset) {
      this.viewer?.context.getScene().remove(subset);
    }
  }
}
```

When I toggle the layer (`toggleLayer()`) I receive an object from the subset like this

[image: Subset Object]

This is my html

```
<div>
  <mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav mode="side" opened>
      <mat-toolbar>
      <span>
        BIM
      </span>
      </mat-toolbar>
      <mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" [value]="loadingValue"></mat-progress-bar>
      <mat-list role="list" *ngIf="!ifcElement">
          <mat-list-item role="listitem">
            Caricamento IFC in corso...
          </mat-list-item>
      </mat-list>
      <mat-accordion *ngIf="ifcElement">
        <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let arch of ifcElement?.children || []">
          <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>
              {{arch.Name?.value || arch.LongName?.value || 'Architettura'}}
            </mat-panel-title>
          </mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <mat-list role="list">
            <mat-list-item role="listitem" *ngFor="let layer of arch.children">
              <mat-checkbox (click)="toggleLayer($event, layer)">
                {{layer.Name?.value || layer.LongName?.value || 'N/A'}}
              </mat-checkbox>
            </mat-list-item>
          </mat-list>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
      </mat-accordion>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
      <div id="viewer-container" #viewerContainer></div>
      <div class="loading-spinner-wrapper" *ngIf="loadingValue!==100">
        <mat-spinner mode="indeterminate" diameter="35"></mat-spinner>
      </div>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
</div>
```

Here the final result in the browser

[image: IFC Viewer]

The issue it's that nothing happens when I toggle the layer. And the subset log looks always the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you load an IFC model, it also gets added to the scene. You need to remove the original model from the scene.

Instead of creating a subset every time the user toggles a layer, you need to create subsets for each layer in the beginning, and just add or remove the subset from the scene when the user toggles a layer. You can find a tutorial about that [here](https://ifcjs.github.io/info/docs/Guide/web-ifc-three/Tutorials/Hiding), the full example [here](https://github.com/IFCjs/hello-world/tree/main/examples/web-ifc-three/hiding) and the working app [here](https://ifcjs.github.io/hello-world/examples/web-ifc-three/hiding/).

The structure of your logic should be similar to the following snippet. This has been extracted from the minimal example linked above, so probably you need to adapt it a bit to you project:

```
import {
    IFCWALLSTANDARDCASE,
    IFCSLAB,
    IFCDOOR,
    IFCWINDOW,
    IFCFURNISHINGELEMENT,
    IFCMEMBER,
    IFCPLATE,
} from 'web-ifc';

//Sets up the IFC loading
const ifcModels = [];
const ifcLoader = new IFCLoader();
ifcLoader.ifcManager.setWasmPath('../../../');
ifcLoader.load('../../../IFC/01.ifc', async (ifcModel) => {
    ifcModels.push(ifcModel);
    await setupAllCategories();
});


// Sets up optimized picking
ifcLoader.ifcManager.setupThreeMeshBVH(
    computeBoundsTree,
    disposeBoundsTree,
    acceleratedRaycast);

// List of categories names
const categories = {
    IFCWALLSTANDARDCASE,
    IFCSLAB,
    IFCFURNISHINGELEMENT,
    IFCDOOR,
    IFCWINDOW,
    IFCPLATE,
    IFCMEMBER,
};

// Gets the name of a category
function getName(category) {
    const names = Object.keys(categories);
    return names.find(name => categories[name] === category);
}

// Gets all the items of a category
async function getAll(category) {
    return ifcLoader.ifcManager.getAllItemsOfType(0, category, false);
}

// Creates a new subset containing all elements of a category
async function newSubsetOfType(category) {
    const ids = await getAll(category);
    return ifcLoader.ifcManager.createSubset({
        modelID: 0,
        scene,
        ids,
        removePrevious: true,
        customID: category.toString(),
    });
}

// Stores the created subsets
const subsets = {};

async function setupAllCategories() {
    const allCategories = Object.values(categories);
    for (let i = 0; i < allCategories.length; i++) {
        const category = allCategories[i];
        await setupCategory(category);
    }
}

// Creates a new subset and configures the checkbox
async function setupCategory(category) {
    subsets[category] = await newSubsetOfType(category);
    setupCheckBox(category);
}

// Sets up the checkbox event to hide / show elements
function setupCheckBox(category) {
    const name = getName(category);
    const checkBox = document.getElementById(name);
    checkBox.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        const checked = event.target.checked;
        const subset = subsets[category];
        if (checked) scene.add(subset);
        else subset.removeFromParent();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks I solved in that way but I had to add also this.model.visibility = false

Answer (score 0):

Subsets or `createSubset()` requires customID along side ids to identify the created subset from the original model without the customID you are overwriting your subset, it can be any string, in the [example](https://github.com/IFCjs/hello-world/blob/main/examples/web-ifc-three/hiding/app.js) its was defined by `category.toString()`

Comment: I added a custom id (customID: '${layer.expressID}-custom-id') as string but still doesn't work. Nothing happens. The subset log it's always the same one no matter which expressID I pass in the method.